# Resource Directory Path Issue in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-x-3.0

3.2 for developing a game.I have developed game in android but facing a problem in iOS i.e

I am facing problem to read resource images.In my game have 3 stages "Simple","Medium" and "Hard".I have put images on the following path

```
# "Simple/1.png","Medium/1.png","Hard/1.png"
# "Simple/2.png","Medium/2.png","Hard/2.png"
# ------------------------------------------
# ------------------------------------------
# "Simple/n.png","Medium/n.png","Hard/n.png"
```

In android getting correct image by using full path of image.
But in iOS it is not working.
How i can fetch image of same name from different directory in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use `FileUtils::addSearchPath()` and add `"Simple"`, `"Medium"` or `"Hard"`, depending on the game stage and then you can use just `"1.png"` to refer to the file from various Cocos2d-x APIs.

Comment: i.e i can't access resource by using it's full path.

Comment: @hiteshlandge No you need to use `FileUtils` to resolve full paths.  I've found the class to be right royal pain; for example under Android it's impossible to enumerate files in a particular sub-directory due to the asset manager.  Also there is no API to write files.

Answer (score 0):

landge,
Please try this:

See my screenshot using cocos2d-x-3.6
http://prntscr.com/7zwty9
It shows Xcode with 3 files with the same name 1.png in different absolute directories: hard/medium/simple.

```
vector<string> searchPaths = fu->getSearchPaths();
fu->addSearchPath("res/medium");
CCLOG("fpff = %s", fu->fullPathForFilename("1.png").c_str());
```

This is the console output:

```
fpff = /Users/javier.fuchs/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/68F9EE6B-2829-420E-9359-00EC30C6372D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E586FE31-AFC2-4052-9826-9B27AA75182A/MyCppGame iOS.app/res/medium/1.png
```

Please make sure where is the file, and take a look of the full path, inside the project.

There is no guaranty with search paths, even if you doing:

```
auto& list = fu->getSearchPaths();
for( const auto &item : list) {
    CCLOG("%s", item.c_str());
}
```

You will see that adding a relative path that does not exist, the relative path will be included anyway.